# position:sticky doesn't work on :first-child selector, what's going on?

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

The problem is, I've seen this working elsewhere. So it should work. I can't catch what's wrong, as the browser dev tools show that the position is set to sticky, but it doesn't stick.

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/Slava_B/qr9tpLmh/

```css
.parent {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.position-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(200, 220, 255, 0.5);
}

.position-first-child-sticky {
  position: relative;
}

.position-first-child-sticky> :first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 220, 200, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="position-sticky">I'm sticky</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="position-first-child-sticky">
    <div>I'm fist-child-sticky</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Latest Firefox and Chrome... Does the second "I'm first-child-sticky" stick too in your browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be no height being added to `.position-first-child-sticky`. If you set the height of this `1000px` then it works. The height could also be set to `inherit`

```
.position-first-child-sticky {
height: 1000px;
}
```

Here's a working example:

```css
.parent{
  height: 1000px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.position-first-child-sticky {
height: 1000px;
}
.position-sticky{
  position:-webkit-sticky;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  background:rgba(200,220,255,0.5);
}
.position-first-child-sticky{position:relative;}
.position-first-child-sticky > :first-child{
  position:-webkit-sticky;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  background:rgba(255,220,200,0.5);
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="position-sticky">I'm sticky</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="position-first-child-sticky">
    <div>
      I'm fist-child-sticky
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because your child element **`.position-first-child-sticky > :first-child`** and its parent container **`.position-first-child-sticky`** are taking the same height in DOM.

> *[A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its
>   containing block crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is
>   treated as fixed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)*

Try to add some height on **`.position-first-child-sticky`** and you will see the difference.

```css
.parent {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.position-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(200, 220, 255, 0.5);
}

.position-first-child-sticky {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.position-first-child-sticky> :first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 220, 200, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="position-sticky">I'm sticky</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="position-first-child-sticky">
    <div>I'm fist-child-sticky</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alph.Dev The position sticky is working fine but its impossible to see the sticky effect because the parent and child element are taking the same height in DOM.

Comment: Sorry, You are absolutely right. I removed the comment as it's no longer true.